# Extracting column names in SAS IML

Tags: sas

I was hoping to write a macro using IML that would be able to extract the column names of the dataset to use as names later.

Some pseudocode:

```
    proc iml;
        read all dataset into matrix_a [colname = varnames];
        (...)
        names = varnames;
        create new_data_set [rownames = names];
    quit;
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure is.

```
data test;
array x[10];
do i=1 to 10;
    do j=1 to 10;
        x[j] = (i-1)*10 + j;
    end;
    output;
end;
drop i j;
run;

proc iml;
use test;
read all var _num_ into test[colname=names];
close test;

test = test`;
names = names`;

create test_t from test[rowname=names];
append from test[rowname=names];
close test_t;
quit;
```